# List comprehension to find matching parens

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to come up with a list comprehension that will match open and close parens. So far I have these two statements which grab two lists of open and close parens separately

```
my_str = "hanz(and(franz/bob())+ 7) + tom(2)"
```

Grab idx of open parens:

```
[ i for i,c in enumerate(my_str) if c == '(']

# [4, 8, 18, 31]
```

Grab idx of close parens:

```
[ i for i,c in enumerate(my_str) if c == ')']

# [19, 20, 24, 33]
```

**What I would like is one handy comprehension that could give me a list of pairs corresponding to each match pair of parens**

i.e.

```
[ ???? for i,c in enumerate(my_str) ???]

# [(4,24), (8,20), (18,19), (31,33)]
```

Comment: This isn't really a job for a list comprehension; is there a reason for it? It's extremely easy with a loop and a stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the proper and simple way to do this is using a stack:

```
my_str = "hanz(and(franz/bob())+ 7) + tom(2)"
stack = []
parens = []
for i, c in enumerate(my_str):
    if c == "(":
        stack.append(i)
    elif c == ")":
        parens.append((stack.pop(), i))
print(parens) # [(18, 19), (8, 20), (4, 24), (31, 33)]
```

But if you value one-liners more than readability or coding conventions, you could also cram that into a list comprehensions with side effects:

```
stack = []
parens = [(stack.pop(), i) for i, c in enumerate(my_str)
          if c == "(" and stack.append(i) or c == ")"]
print(parens) # [(18, 19), (8, 20), (4, 24), (31, 33)]
```

This uses the fact that `and` and `or` are short-circuit-evaluated, thus it will `append` items only if `c == "("`, but then fail because `append` return `None`, and only add elements to the results if the second condition, `c == ")"` is true, popping the position of the most recent `(` from the stack.

At least, it is not a total abuse of list comprehensions, as the result is not discarded but actually the desired result, and it's probably still easier to comprehend than the three list comprehensions that [you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53324025/1639625) have (although those work without side effects), but the better solution for a "handy" way to do this would be: Make it a function, than it does not matter how many lines it has.

Comment: `with side effects` cracked me up! Also it's funny because it's true

Answer (score 0):

Like @Tordek mentioned, though not impossible this is not very practical,

For the sake of completeness however, here's a solution:

```
my_str = "hanz(and(franz/bob())+ 7) + tom(2)"

 pt_arr = [ 1 if c == '(' else -1 for i,c in enumerate(my_str ) if c == ')' or c == '(']
idx_arr = [ i for i,c in enumerate(my_str ) if c == ')' or c == '(']

[(idx_arr[strt_idx],idx_arr[strt_idx + [j for j,d in enumerate([ sum(pt_arr[strt_idx:i + 1]) for i,c in enumerate(pt_arr) if i >= strt_idx]) if d == 0][0]]) for strt_idx,f in enumerate(pt_arr) if f == 1]

# [(4,24), (8,20), (18,19), (31,33)]
```